# Importing from txt

Tags: import

I have the below txt file and I want to import it in mathematica, to kick the headers and keep a neat 2 column table or matrix for ploting.

Since I am new in mathematica I have trouble with finding the way to do it.

If you have any suggestions I would be grateful.

Thank you!

```
LECROYMAUI,0,Waveform
Segments,1,SegmentSize,253
Segment,TrigTime,TimeSinceSegment1
"#1,24-Oct-2017 09:46:30,0"
Time,Ampl
0,-85.0822
1192.09,-81.8994
2384.19,-83.4981
3576.28,-85.526
4768.37,-86.9433
5960.47,-87.5171
7152.56,-88.7014
8344.65,-89.5351
9536.74,-91.1045
10728.8,-92.1466
11920.9,-91.3006
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data=Import["input.txt","CSV"];
```

Now pull the numeric data out

```
data=Cases[data,{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>{x,y}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[data,Mesh->Full,MeshStyle->Red,Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{{"y(x)",None},{"x","My data"}},
    GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray,BaseStyle->14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly.